# Print Boost Python object

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have a Boost Python object

```
py::object obj = whatever();
```

I want to print it using normal python rules.

```
// I want the effect of print 'My object is ', obj
std::cout << "My object is " << obj << std::endl;
```

This does not compile with a huge compiler dump. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Boost.Python, but I am not sure it has an `operator<<(ostream &)` defined for `py::object`.

Comment: You'd probably just want to write the equivalent code to call Python's `str()` function passing `obj` as the argument, and convert the return value to an `std::string`, and stream that out. You could provide your own `operator<<(ostream &, py::object const &)` to provide the streaming operator for all Python objects using this approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Boost.Python doesn't come with an `operator<<(ostream&, const object&)` but we can write our own to mimic what Python would do natively: call `str`:

```
namespace py = boost::python;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const py::object& o)
{
    return os << py::extract<std::string>(py::str(o))();
}
```